# Is it correct to call an asynctask inside a service?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I try to call an asynctask in the "onLocationChanged" method but the asynctask never receives the parameters. My service gets my coordinates for every change in my location and works well showing them in console.

**In my Service**

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location){

        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

        Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
        mLastLocation.set(location);

        JSONObject actualPosition = new JSONObject();

        try {

            actualPosition.put("Latitude", latitude);
            actualPosition.put("Longitude", longitude);

            new AsyncTaskServerPosition.SendToServer().execute(actualPosition.toString());

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

---

**Edit**

**My asynctask**

```
public class AsyncTaskServerPosition{

private static final String TAG = "ASYNCTASK";
private static UserSessionManager session;


public static class SendToServer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... location) {

        try {

            HashMap<String, String> user = session.obtenerRolyId();
            String userId = user.get(UserSessionManager.KEY_ID);

            Log.d(TAG, "Location: " +location);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            String actualPosition = location[0];
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            OutputStream os = null;
            InputStream inputStream = null;

            URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8081/odata/Usuarios("+userId+")/ActualizarPosicion");
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            urlConnection.connect();

            os = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            os.write(actualPosition.getBytes());

            os.flush();
            os.close();

            int serverResponse = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            String serverMsg = urlConnection.getResponseMessage();
            urlConnection.disconnect();

            Log.d(TAG, "Code: " + serverResponse + " - Menssage: " + serverMsg);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("error", e.toString());
        }

        return "call";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    }

}}
```

**Service complete**

```
public class ServicePosition extends Service{

private static final String TAG = "TESTGPS";
private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 1000;
private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 10f;

UserSessionManager session;

private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener{

    Location mLastLocation;
    public LocationListener(String provider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
        mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {

        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

        Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
        mLastLocation.set(location);

        JSONObject actualPosition = new JSONObject();

        try {

            actualPosition.put("Latitud", latitude);
            actualPosition.put("Longitud", longitude);

            new AsyncTaskServerPosition.SendToServer().execute(actualPosition.toString());

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
    }
}
LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[] {
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
};
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
{
    return null;
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
    initializeLocationManager();
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListeners[1]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "No puede solicitar la actualización de la ubicacion", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "El proveedor de gps no existe, " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListeners[0]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "No puede solicitar la actualización de la ubicacion", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "El proveedor de gps no existe " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mLocationManager != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
            try {
                mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listners, ignore", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
private void initializeLocationManager() {
    Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
    if (mLocationManager == null) {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }
}}
```

Comment: Pls provide your impl of the async task `AsyncTaskServerPosition`

Comment: I dont think its good Idea to send request every sec  ..  
i prefer to send location when there distance between  previous and current location

Comment: Add my code, thanks for helping.

Comment: @Elsunhoty Sorry, I wrote wrong, my service gets my coordinates for every change in my location.

Comment: How are you determining that the AsyncTask doesn't get the location?

Comment: Debugging and using logcat, also, my web service does not register what I send.

Comment: What is printed from this log statement in the AsyncTask? `Log.d(TAG, "Location: " +location);`

Comment: Nothing, the registry does not appear on the console. Apparently never calls asynctask...